# How do I get started with this?

Tags: r

[image: homework problem I am stuck on]

So I am stuck on this problem for a long time. 
I was think I should first create the two functions, like this:

```
n = runif(10000)
int sum = 0
estimator1_fun = function(n){
  for(i in 1:10000){
    sum = sum + ((n/i)*runif(1))
  )
  return (sum)
}
```

and do the same for the other function, and use the mse formula? Am I even approaching this correctly? I tried formatting it, but found that using an image would be better.

Comment: Write a more descriptive title for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming U(0,Theta_0) is the uniform distribution from 0 to Theta_0, and that Theta_0 is a fixed constant, I would proceed as follows:

```
1. Define Theta_0. Give it a fixed value.
2. Write the function that gives a random number from that distribution
   - The distribution function is runif(0,Theta_0). 
   - Arguments could be Theta_0 and N.
3. Sample it a few thousand (or whatever) times into a vector X.
4. Calculate the two estimates.
5. Repeat steps 3 & 4 for more samples
6. Plot the two estimates against the number of samples and 
       see if it is approaching Theta_0
```

Comment: That should be enough... I am not going to write the code for you.